# How to Solve Not Compatible Python Libraries on Google Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, google-kubernetes-engine

```
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
    self.handle_request`enter code here`(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 178, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 130, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 114, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 152, in handle_uncaught_exception
    callback = resolver.resolve_error_handler(500)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 615, in resolve_error_handler
    callback = getattr(self.urlconf_module, 'handler%s' % view_type, None)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 595, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/vmagent/app/mysite/urls.py", line 38, in <module>
    re_path(r'^rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls'))
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rosetta/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rosetta/views.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .translate_utils import TranslationException, translate
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rosetta/translate_utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    "urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently "
ImportError: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016'. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2168
```

Above is my Google Kubernetes Engine Pod logs,
I found many packages not support
my dev project mostly install latest packages and use latest version of framework, When I deployment the project on GKE, I got these issue.

How to fix please?
I don't want to delete and redo with for a compatible.

Comment: Try updating you environment to something more recent than python 3.7

Comment: I tried gcr.io/google_appengine/python to check this repository show latest is python 2.7, I am with Google Cloud so, experienced people please share about solving issue.

Comment: As your dev project is deployed in GKE and as per this [GKE Official doc](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/container/latest#supported-python-versions), Google kubernetes engine supports `Python >= 3.7` and it unsupported Python <= 3.6. So, As WombatPM  suggested, you need to upgrade your python version to >= 3.7. This might help you resolve your issue. Notice: Python 2 is no longer supported by the community. We recommend that you [migrate Python 2 apps to Python 3.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences)

Comment: I have delete the GKE Cluster, I want to create new one, Also my Dockerfile also update like this:
FROM python:3.11.5

Comment: @Kuth : As you want to create a new GKE Cluster by using docker file , can you refer to this [Deploy an app to a GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deploy-app-cluster#dockerfile) and [GKE Overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/kubernetes-engine-overview) let me know whether the shared above information is helped you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As your dev project is deployed in GKE and as per this [GKE Official doc,](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/container/latest#supported-python-versions) Google kubernetes engine supports Python >= 3.7 and unsupported Python <= 3.6. So, As WombatPM  suggested, you need to upgrade your python version to >= 3.7. This might help you resolve your issue. Notice: Python 2 is no longer supported by the community. We recommend that you [migrate Python 2 apps to Python 3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences).
- Also you want to create a new GKE Cluster by using docker file , can you refer to this [Deploy an app to a GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deploy-app-cluster#dockerfile) and [GKE Overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/kubernetes-engine-overview) .
- Instead of creating a new environment, you can also upgrade to the latest python version by using this command `pipenv install --python 3.11` and also refer to this i[nstallation guide](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/).

Comment: I can see you are getting this error also `ImportError: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016'` along with above steps refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76187415/19230181) by Philippe Sisowath to clear  Openssl and URLLIB error.

Comment: I have update my Dockerfile  file for Python 3.11.5 but will error with activate environment.

Comment: Can you share the error you are facing?

Comment: 'code'>>> RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
 'code'22 |
 'code' 23 |     # Copy your application code to the container
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -c pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1'

I think problem on my code to command activate env and install package.

Comment: Exit Code 1 indicates that a file reference in the image/package is used to run the container, which points to a nonexistent file. So, As per this [Python PIP install requirement doc](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pip-install-requirements/), Place requirements.txt in the directory where you plan to run the command. If the file is in a different directory, you need to specify its path like `path/to/requirements.txt`.

Comment: @Kuth : Upvote or accept this answer if it helps you give some solution and also As per this [stack rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275909/19230181), ask this error as a new question so that whoever has advanced  knowledge on python or similar  kind of error handling can answer.

Comment: Now Environment issue has been fixed with Official tutorial.