# Libressl appears in the local/opt file, but when I run the libressl version, it does not appear on my computer

Tags: python, pycharm, openssl, urllib3, libressl

I installed it with libress homebrew. It appears when I type brew list, but it does not appear in my computer's public bin folder. When I type libressl version it doesn't appear either.

I need to work with selenium in Pycharm. The error I get in the terminal when I run the code:

NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'LibreSSL 2.8.3'. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/3020

I have a libressl file under the /usr/local/opt folder.

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libressl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
I tried to export libress but I couldn't. When I try to install it again, it says homebrew is already installed.

UPDATED : Update: There appears to be a libressl arma file in /usr/local/bin. But when I type the libressl version terminal code, I still don't get any results. There is no file about libressl in /usr/bin either
```

.

Comment: Please make sure you question doesn't have any typos, because if so, the changes to your PATH do.

Comment: My paths seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error on my macOS Monterey (12.6.8) when using the Python version provided by macOS. I resolved it with the help of these posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58190880/12030278
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76344709/12030278

Initially, I changed my default macOS Python version to one installed via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Additionally, I performed the following trick:

```
pip uninstall urllib3
pip install 'urllib3<2.0'
```

**If you are using an editor like Visual Studio Code (or others), remember to change the Python default interpreter path to /usr/local/bin/python instead of /usr/bin!**

I hope this information proves helpful.

Comment: I solved the problem by downgrading the urllib3 version. I couldn't find any other solution. Thank you for your answer.